# GlobalAddAtom() returns 0 and GetLastError = 0x5 on Win7, works on XP

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-7

Simple code:

```
ATOM atom = GlobalAddAtom(L"TestCpp1");
```

It returns 0 and GetLastError returns 0x5 (Access Denied). Nothing on MSDN about it.
This is on Win7. Admin rights make no difference.

Same code works on XP. AddAtom (local) works on Win7.

What's causing this?

Comment: You are running it as administrator, right?  Maybe it needs a manifest (possibly with uiAccess set to true); this is just a wild guess.

Comment: I couldn't get uiAccess=true to work because I couldn't figure out how to sign the app but running it as admin makes no difference whatsoever...

Comment: Could you please add a short statement answering this detail: *Is this a GUI or Console application?* (maybe a short edit note to make this Q&A more helpful for others) Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Wolf I'd be happy to oblige but this was 5 years ago and I can hardly remember... I think it was console app but don't quote me on it :)

Comment: @georgiosd thanks for the late comment, and yes: console seems logical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this a GUI or Console application? One thing you might try is to explicity call LoadLibrary("User32") before calling GlobalAddAtom.

Here is a reference to someone that had a similar problem, on XP maybe this is relevant?
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2004-03/0851.html

Comment: No freakin' way... I did see this message but I couldn't figure out what the man was saying - thanks for decoding it for me, it works like this.

Comment: wow. Does this serve as evidence that User32 functions have an if statement that loads the library if its not loaded, and that GlobalAddAtom and GlobalFindAtom don't do this check? Since you can repleace `LoadLibraray("User32")` with `MessageBoxA(NULL, "_", "_", 0)` and it will still work.

Comment: Thanks! this really helped!